# Android WebView with CSS modification of hr tag

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I am working on an app which needs to display some dynamically queried
HTML content, including CSS.
WebView seems to be the best implementation for this type of work.

I ran into an error when testing it out, and tracked it down to the
following css tag:

hr{width:100%!important}

Android WebView seems to be incapable of displaying any html that
includes this line.
Some research shows that the  attribute was deprecated
(link: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_hr_width.asp), but it works
on all browsers.

Below is some html, including this line.  It will render fine in any
browser.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type=\"text/css\">
      hr{width:100%!important}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Some text
  </body>
</html>
```

And, in Android:

```
           String exampleCSS = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">" +
                           "hr{width:100%!important}" +
                           "</style></head><body>" +
                           "Some text" +
                           "</body></html>";
           WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_html_about);
           webView.loadData(exampleCSS, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

The result is a "Web page not available" error in the webview.

Is this a known issue due to deprecation?  Is it a bug with WebView?
Is there any known work around for such issues?

Comment: While the webview shouldn't break like that, I would try not inlining the CSS. Get all your CSS in one place (or a few places).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the android webview passes content using the data:// scheme, and as a result, you would have to urlencode the content for it to work as expected.
In my case, the css/html is provided to me, so I had to use the following work around:

Example

```
    ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_body)).loadDataWithBaseURL(null, content, null, "utf-8", null);
```

This seems to work, and get passed this particular issue above.
Thanks to all that answered.
Dale.

Answer (score 2):

Hr is not depreciated, though it has been given symantic meaning. It indicates a change in content.

I'm not sure what is causing your issue, but I can tell you your markup as written is unnecessary. Hr is a block level element, and so it already has a 100% width.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Chris.  You're correct, but the source HTML is not my own, so I had no control over that.